# CMS page title in custom template file

Tags: magento2

How to get cms page title and page content in custom template file

I tried below code to display title but its not working

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 echo $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory')->load('contact-us', 'identifier')->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get CMS page title.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$ModelPageFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory');
$page_title = $ModelPageFactory->create()->load('home')->getTitle();
print_r($page_title);
```

Not recommended to use object manager. You can make the dependency as added

```
...
use Magento/Cms/Model/PageFactory;

protected $pageFactory;

public function __construct(...,PageFactory $pagefactory,...) {
...
$this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
...
}

public function loadCMSPage() {
...
$page = $this->pageFactory->create()->load(<PAGE URL OR ID HERE>);
...
}
```